# Ошибка max в C++

Tags: c++, max

Недавно наткнулся на проблему в c++. Есть переменная int mx и есть сет set vals, надо переменной mx передать значение max(mx, vals.size()), но max ломается. Подскажите как засолвить проблему пожалуйста.

```
int mx = 0;
set <int> vals;
mx = max(vals.size(), mx);
```

Comment: `max<int>(vals.size(), mx);`?

Comment: Сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что `max` - это шаблон функции. Давайте посмотрим на обьявление этого шаблона:

```
template< class T >
constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b );
```

Как видно, два аргумента имеют одинаковый тип. Теперь посмотрим на Ваш вызов `max`:

```
max(vals.size(), mx);
```

Так в чём проблема? Проблема в том, что `vals.size()` возвращает значение, которое имеет тип `size_t`. А `mx` имеет тип `int`. Получается, что типы разные и компилятор не может определить нужный тип. Поэтому нужно явно указать какой тип использовать. Для этого просто укажите необходимый тип в угловых скобках после имени функции. Вот так:

```
max<int>(vals.size(), mx);
```

Answer (score 4):

Надо перевести `mx` в тип `std::size_t` либо изначально его таким создать.

```
std::max(vals.size(), static_cast<std::size_t>(mx));
```